# Validate the input variable and action further

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell

In my script, have a input variable called `$inputVar` this can be a number like `2`,`3`,`4` but will be single integer or this can be comma separated value like `2,3,4,5`.

want if it is a integer then do nothing, but if it a comma separated variable then print each element inside the comma separated,

for example:

```
 if  ($inputVar is an integer) {
}
else {
   foreach ($var in $inputVar){
    Write-Host $var
}
}
```

Comment: A better approach might be to accept a _list_ (or an _array_) of integers, and then action based on whether there's 0, 1, or more of them? Can you describe the purpose of this exercise a little further? Describe the context, the function/script you're working on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if `$inputvar` is a **string** like "1" or "1,2,3" or an **integer value** like `1` or an **array** of integers like `1,2,3`..

When it's a **string** you could split the $inputvar on possible commas, force that into an array even if there is only one value in it by surrounding it with `@()` and then use the `.Count` property like:

```
$inputvar = "1,2,3"
if (@($inputvar -split ',').Count -gt 1) { Write-Host ($inputvar -replace ',', [environment]::NewLine) }
```

When it is not a string, but an array of integers or a single integer value, you could do:

```
$inputvar = 1,2,3
# (`!` is the same as `-not`)
if (![int]::TryParse($inputvar, [ref]$null)) { $inputvar | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }}
```

or

```
if ($inputvar -is [array]) { $inputvar | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }}
```